# Count consequitive numbers in a string C#

Tags: c#

I have a string {101110111010001111} I'm searching for the total number of all sequences of equal bits with an exact length of 3 bits. In above string the answer willbe 3 (please note that the last one "1111" doesn't count as it has more than 3 equal bits.
Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: Can you add another example ... or more its hard to make out what you are trying... splitting the the string into chunks of 3 and get the count of the distinct patterns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it that you  need? Sometimes the simplest solutions are the best:

```
public static int Count(string txt)
{
    // TODO validation etc
    var result = 0;
    char lstChr = txt[0];
    int lastChrCnt = 1;

    for (var i = 1; i < txt.Length; i++)
    {
        if (txt[i] == lstChr)
        {
            lastChrCnt += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (lastChrCnt == 3)
            {
                result += 1;
            }

            lstChr = txt[i];
            lastChrCnt = 1;
        }
    }

    return lastChrCnt == 3 ? result + 1 : result;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want a simple solution, try this:

```
string s = "1101110111010001111";
var regex = new Regex(@"(.)\1+");
var matches = regex.Matches(s);
int count = matches.Cast<Match>().Where(x => x.Length == 3).Count();
```

Explanation:

- The regex finds sets of 2 or more identical characters (not limited to 0's and 1's)
- Then only sets of exactly 3 characters are counted

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression:

```
Regex.Matches(s, @"((?<=0)|^)111((?=0)|$)|((?<=1)|^)000((?=1)|$)");
```

Here's the same expression with comments:

```
Regex.Matches(s, @"
    (
        (?<=0)           # is preceeded by a 0
        |                # or
        ^                # is at start
    )
    111                  # 3 1's
    (
        (?=0)            # is followed by a 0
        |                # or
        $                # is at start
    )
    |                    # - or -
    (
        (?<=1)           # is preceeded by a 1
        |                # or
        ^                # is at start
    )
    000                  # 3 0's
    (
        (?=1)            # followed by a 1
        |                # or
        $                # is at end
    )", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace).Dump();
```

Comment: Note that this falls squarely in the "... now you have two problems" category. I am not entirely sure this is a good solution, but posted for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string by "111" to get an array. You can then simply count the lines that not begins with "1" with the linq.

See the sample:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace experiment
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string data = "{101110111010001111}";
            string[] sequences = data.Split(new string[] {"111"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
            int validCounts = sequences.Count(i => i.Substring(0, 1) != "1");
            Console.WriteLine("Count of sequences: {0}", validCounts);
            // See the splited array
            foreach (string item in sequences) {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thus the zeroes (000) are not counted - the result has to be 3 from the following sequences of 3 same bits (111 (position 2 to 4), 111(positions 6 to 8) and 000 (positions 11 to 13)). The last one 1111 (positions 14 to 17) are not counted because it contains 4 same bits in a row, not 3 only

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach: Since you are only counting bits, you can split the string by "1" and "0" and then count all elements with lenght 3:

```
string inputstring = "101110111010001111";
string[] str1 = inputstring.Split('0');
string[] str2 = inputstring.Split('1');
int result = str1.Where(s => s.Length == 3).Count() + str2.Where(s => s.Length == 3).Count();
return result
```

Comment: I would suggest you rather go with the solution of Hans Kesting - that one is a lot more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

An algorithmic solution. Checks for any n consecutive characters. But this is not completely tested for all negative scenarios.

```
public static int GetConsecutiveCharacterCount(this string input, int n)
{
   // Does not contain expected number of characters
   if (input.Length < n || n < 1)
      return 0;

   return Enumerable.Range(0, input.Length - (n - 1)) // Last n-1 characters will be covered in the last but one iteration.
                    .Where(x => Enumerable.Range(x, n).All(y => input[x] == input[y]) && // Check whether n consecutive characters match
                                ((x - 1) > -1 ? input[x] != input[x - 1] : true) && // Compare the previous character where applicable
                                ((x + n) < input.Length ? input[x] != input[x + n] : true) // Compare the next character where applicable
                     )
                    .Count();
}
```